# Printing objects inside a lib file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, static-libraries

What is the command to print .o files inside a .a file inside ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`man ar` tells you the syntax is `ar t name/of/lib` as in `ar t /usr/lib/libc.a`

Comment: Should clarify that this is on a system using GNU `ar`, not sure if other archivers use different syntax. Also, if you want to look at the symbols inside of the various object files within the archive, check out `nm`